# Send parallelly multiple http requests with different authorization header .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, concurrency

I do load test for my multitenant authorization of API. So I created list of HttpClients, assign different headers (e.g. Authorization) to them. Then I created 2000 Tasks which uses these HttpClients to send requests parallelly. Now I get problems like ***"no connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it"*** and of course I'm aware of that using multiple  HttpClients is not recommended because it can exhaust the number of sockets available and it keeps ports open after applications execution is finished

**How to send multiple parallel http requests with different authorization headers?**

Comment: Are you creating new httpClients per tenant? Would the header be same per tenant?

Comment: @SharathNS Yes and Yes

Comment: See following which uses Maximum Degree of Parallelism : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library?redirectedfrom=MSDN&force_isolation=true#degree-of-parallelism

Comment: @freak_geek Can you add some extra information on the environment you running it. like Linux, windows server, win 10, everything is running in the same machine, etc..

Comment: _"no connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it"_ sounds like your web-server does not allow so many concurrent request. What is the http status code you get and do you test against a debug or release build? Also, please show the code with which you do the parallel requests

Comment: I run it locally on windows, send requests from different machine in the same network, I turned off firewall, I know that likely web-server does not allow so many concurrent request because I have multiple HttpClients but I do not know how to use only one which will be sending parallel requests with different auth header,  but I'm looking for other solution to run a load tests too. To do parallel requests I just simply create multiple tasks. Every of them send request using one httpClient from list. I run them all using  Task.WhenAll(tasksList);